# Go back to the previous Salesforce Page?

Tags: visualforce, excel, navigation

I have two pages, each with their own controller. One page has a commandButton that when clicked returns a PageReference to the second page. The second page simply has data table- this page is rendered as an Excel file:

```
<apex:page controller="ResultController" contentType="application/vnd.ms-excel#SalesForceExport.xls"  >
</apex:page>
```

When you go to the URL of the second page, an Excel file automatically downloads and the blank page just sits there. What I would like to do is either:

a) When user clicks on the command button on the first page, excel file should just download there OR
b) When user clicks on the command button on the first page, the browser would go to the second page, excel file downloads, and the browser automatically goes back to the previous page.

Ideally, I would like to implement option "a" but any hints would be appreciated.

Comment: The key will be in the button that calls the other page. What is the code for your current button?

Comment: Try having same controller for both pages if you can?